# Is there a python package that reads the underlying xml of ms office files?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, office365, powerpoint

I want to read the XML of a PPTX file in python and basically save the string / data structure into a variable.

I couldn't find a package that let's me do this with Python yet.

Answer (score 5):

If I'm understanding correctly, you can just use the builtin `zipfile` module.

```
import zipfile
archive = zipfile.ZipFile('<My Powerpoint Name>.pptx', 'r')
xml_file = archive.open('[Content_Types].xml')
text = xml_file.read()
print(text)
```

This will print out the xml text from the `[Content_Types].xml` directly inside the archive.

If you want to parse the XML you can use the builtin `xml` module.

```
import zipfile
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

archive = zipfile.ZipFile('<My Powerpoint Name>.pptx', 'r')
xml_file = archive.open('[Content_Types].xml')
text = xml_file.read()

root = ET.fromstring(text)
value_to_find = r'application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml'
for child in root:
    if child.attrib['ContentType'] == value_to_find:
        print(child.attrib)
```

Comment: I want the xml output that is behind a specific content type `"contentType="application/vnd.openxmlformats-package.relationships+xml"`
Do you know how I can get this output?

Comment: I think what you're asking is how to parse the xml. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to reply but what I want is the underlying xml behind that value. That information is not in the [Content_Types].xml file as far as I can see but I do not know where to access it. I also opened the pptx as a zip to check for the file myself in the explorer but it does not seem to be in there.